# config codeigniter to run first project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using xampp and my document root in apache is set to htdocs directory by default.  I download Codeigniter and unzip the project into this directory. It runs fine. Now I would like to use CI to create my own project. In the controllers folder I would like to create a folder named “myproject” and in the views folder of application folder, I would like to create a folder named “myproject_view” in which I will store all of my view files. My problem is I don’t know how to reset my config file (especially the route.php) for my project to work then.

CodeIgniter documentation doesn’t have a section to specify how to do this, the information given in URI Routing chapter is not enough for readers to understand this at all. Plus, What if I also would like to store my controler files in a nested folder (controllers > somefolder > someanotherfolders > etc) ? Thank you very much.

[**UPDATE**]
If you only leave all controller in controllers folder, and view files in the views folder, then things work out easily, what if you create a folder in teh controllers and a folder for view in the views folder. I guess you need to change your default route configuration. I would like to know HOW ?

Comment: what do you mean by "reset"? also, the last time I checked CI it was *very* well documented.

Comment: If you only leave all controller in controllers folder, and view files in the views folder, then things work out easily, what if you create a folder in teh controllers and a folder for view in the views folder. I guess you need to change your default route configuration. I would like to know HOW ?

Comment: It looks very clear to me.. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders  just rewrite the desired path to the subfolder

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter's documentation covers [Sub-Folders for Controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders).

Views on the other hand, are always loaded from controllers. Therefore, you can write:

`$this->load->view('my_folder_name/my_view');`

Routes are not required here.